# Python 3.4 определение языка ввода в win7

Tags: python, winapi

Пытаюсь сделать проверку на каком языке пользователь вводит текст с помощью **win32api**.
Там есть методы **win32api.GetKeyboardLayout()** и **win32api.GetKeyboardLayoutName()**, но при проверке этих методов всегда возвращается одно и тоже значение, хотя я меняю язык ввода.

В продолжение, я посмотрел коды ракладок в реестре ("00000409" и "00000419", к примеру) и пытаюсь программно переключить раскладку при помощи **win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout("00000419",1)** (1 нужна для того, чтобы загруженная раскладка сразу активироваласть согласно документации), но опять же раскладка не переключается.

Пробовал на вин7 и вин8.1. В чем может быть проблема? Может быть как-то иначе можно определить текущий язык ввода?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея [кода](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/win_GetKeyboardLayout_for_console.py) взята из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379713/cant-get-current-keyboard-layout/12383335#12383335). Если мы отдадим `GetKeyboardLayout` гуяшный поток, он выдаст правильные значения раскладки, что мы и сделали в этом коде:

```
from ctypes import *
user32 = windll.user32
kernel32 = windll.kernel32


class RECT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("left", c_ulong),
        ("top", c_ulong),
        ("right", c_ulong),
        ("bottom", c_ulong)
    ]


class GUITHREADINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("cbSize", c_ulong),
        ("flags", c_ulong),
        ("hwndActive", c_ulong),
        ("hwndFocus", c_ulong),
        ("hwndCapture", c_ulong),
        ("hwndMenuOwner", c_ulong),
        ("hwndMoveSize", c_ulong),
        ("hwndCaret", c_ulong),
        ("rcCaret", RECT)
    ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gti = GUITHREADINFO(cbSize=sizeof(GUITHREADINFO))
    user32.GetGUIThreadInfo(0, byref(gti))

    dwThread = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(gti.hwndActive, 0)
    lang = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(dwThread)
    print(hex(lang))
```

Раскопал из своего старого проекта код для получения языка раскладки, который после использовал для прогрузки словарей слов. Смотрите значение `GetKeyboardLayout( 0 )`:

```
QString getTheCurrentLanguageKeyboardLayouts()
{
    const int hexKeyLanguageRussian = 0x419;
    const int hexKeyLanguageEnglish = 0x409;

    QString name = QApplication::keyboardInputLocale().name();
    switch( LOWORD ( GetKeyboardLayout( 0 ) ) )
    {
    case hexKeyLanguageRussian:
        name = "ru";
        break;
    case hexKeyLanguageEnglish:
        name = "en";
        break;
    }

    return name;
}
```

Проверка теории о правильной работе `GetKeyboardLayout` для оконных приложений. Это кнопка, которая вызывает функцию, печатающую в консоль текущую раскладку:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

import ctypes

def foo():
    print(hex(ctypes.windll.user32.GetKeyboardLayout(0)))

pb = QPushButton()
pb.clicked.connect(foo)
pb.show()

app.exec_()
```

**UPDATE.** Результат расследования добавил в начало ответа.

Comment: возможно, я что-то не понимаю, я пытался использовать ф-ю GetKeyboardLayout() как без аргумента так и с 0 в качестве аргумента.

Comment: Как я проверяю её: в интерактивном режиме ввожу ф-ю, меняю язык сочетанием клавиш, снова ввожу ф-ю, вывод тот же.

Comment: Как гугл говорит, всегда одно значение возвращается из-за того, что вызываемый процесс не имеет окон. Для консоли нужно немного заморочиться, чтобы возвращало правильную раскладку.

Comment: Действительно, для окон определяет как надо