# как узнать язык клавиатуры выбранным пользователем?

Tags: python, python-3.x

как узнать язык клавиатуры  выбранным пользователем  ?

Comment: [В этой теме возможно есть ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510802/python-3-4-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-win7)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python 3.4 определение языка ввода в win7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510802/python-3-4-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-win7)